# xkeyval: how to use default key value?

Tags: xkeyval

I am trying to use the `xkeyval` package to include key arguments in a new environment. It seems to work except for default values. Here's my best try so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}


\makeatletter
\define@key{Mystuff}{foo}[what]{\def\foo{#1}}
\define@key{Mystuff}{bar}[whatever]{\def\bar{#1}}
\savekeys{Mystuff}{foo,bar}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]%
{\setkeys{Mystuff}{#1}BEGIN \foo}
{END \bar}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[bar=BAAAR]
Uh?
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

But this will cause LaTeX to complain about 
`\foo` being undefined:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\myenv [#1]->\setkeys {Mystuff}{#1}BEGIN \foo 

l.18 \begin{myenv}[bar=BAAAR]
```

And the output will be something like "`BEGIN Uh? END BAAAR`" (without the default "what" value to `\foo`).

What am I doing wrong there, and how can I change this example so the default value for `\foo` will be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default value is used when you specify the key, but don't assign a value: `\begin{myenv}[foo]` will define `\foo` to `what`. Say

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]%
{\setkeys{Mystuff}{foo,bar,#1}BEGIN \foo}
{END \bar}
```

so that the default values will be applied.

Or say

```
\define@key{Mystuff}{foo}{\def\foo{#1}}
\define@key{Mystuff}{bar}{\def\bar{#1}}
```

and

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]%
{\setkeys{Mystuff}{foo=what,bar=whatever,#1}BEGIN \foo}
{END \bar}
```

A key is *never* evaluated if it's not specified in `\setkeys`.

---

Actually, as pointed out by Ulrike Fischer and Ahmed Musa, one can "preset" some keys, and this will be equivalent to specify them in the `\setkeys` list:

```
\define@key{Mystuff}[what]{foo}{\def\foo{#1}}
\define@key{Mystuff}[whatever]{bar}{\def\bar{#1}}
\presetkeys{Mystuff}{foo,bar}{}
```

What strategy to employ depends mostly on the applications. If you *always* need that `foo` and `bar` are set, then `\presetkeys` is more economical, as the assignment wouldn't be performed twice when the key is specified.

The `\presetkeys`, however, can go also in the definition of the environment, so  the definition of your environment can be

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]%
  {\presetkeys{foo,bar}{}%
   \setkeys{Mystuff}{#1}BEGIN \foo}
  {END \bar}
```

and this wouldn't influence other environments using the `Mystuff` keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works (and I understnad the  mechanism better now).

Comment: @egreg: In `xkeyvals` keys *are* evaluated by `\setkeys` even if they are not specified explicitly in the key list if you preset them with `\presetkeys`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know. I think that the two methods both have pros and cons: it all depends on the actual application.

Comment: So, if I have a key family for which I'd like the defaults to be always the same, I can use `\presetkeys`, and if I want to be able to specify the defaults in each `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment`, I would use `\setkeys` with them in the new defined command, as @egreg showed. Sounds really good (very flexible)! :-)

Comment: `\setkeys{Mystuff}{foo=what,bar=whatever,#1}` will most likely result in setting the same keys twice: once by the hardwired `foo=what,bar=whatever` and again by `#1`. `\presetkeys` will not set from the preset list the keys whose values have been supplied by the user (in `#1` in the above example).

Comment: @Ahmed Musa: but using `\setkeys{Mystuff}{foo=what,bar=whatever,#1}` still works if I want these defaults for only one command or environment (and not for all that use the Mystuff family), right?

Comment: @Jay: Your best bet is to use `\presetkeys`, since your keys may eventually grow in number. There will be no point setting them twice needlessly. There are facilities in *ltxkeys* package that will automatically set up the defaults for you and the syntaxes there look like those of *xkeyval* package. For example, look at `\ltxkeys@declarekeys`.

Answer (score 3):

`\savekeys` is the wrong command. What you want is

`\presetkeys{Mystuff}{foo,bar}{}`

The key `foo` will then be inserted at the start of the `\setkeys` list.